# Point On a Plane Closest to a Point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, vectors

1. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the plane containing the points $(-3,4,-2)$, $(1,4,0)$, and $(3,2,-1)$.
   Find the point in this plane that is closest to $(0,3,-1)$.

---

2. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the plane containing the points $(-3,4,-2)$, $(1,4,0)$, and $(3,2,-1)$.
   Let $\ell$ be the line containing the points $(2, 4, -3)$ and $(-1, -1, -9)$.
   Find the intersection of the plane $\mathcal{P}$ and the line $\ell$.

---

I don't know where to start.  I don't know any formulas for calculating a closest point.

Comment: For 1. Allow the point $(0,3,-1)$ to be the origin of your system, and find the point with least magnitude, indicating that it is closest to the point.

Comment: As an additional hint, the equation of a plane is given by $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1.

The equation of the plane containing the points $(−3,4,−2)$, $(1,4,0)$ and $(3,2,−1)$ is given by 
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
x & y & z & 1 \\ 
-3 & 4 & -2 & 1 \\
1 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & -1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
&= 0
\end{align*}

or, $x + 2y - 2z - 9 = 0$

The vector normal to this plane is given by $(1, 2, -2)$

The point in this plane that is closest to $(0,3,−1)$ must be the foot of the perpendicular from this point to the above plane.

The equation of the perpendicular is

$\frac{x - 0}{1} = \frac{y-3}{2} = \frac{z+1}{-2} = k$

or, $x = k, y = 2k + 3, z = -2k-1$

Putting this in the equation of the plane,

$k + 2(2k+3) + 2(2k+1) - 9 = 0$

or, $k = \frac{1}{9}$

Hence the point is $(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{29}{9}, -\frac{11}{9})$

Problem 2.

The equation of the line containing the points $(2,4,−3)$ and $(−1,−1,−9)$ is given by

$\frac{x - 2}{-1-2} = \frac{y-4}{-1-4} = \frac{z+3}{-9+3} = t$

or, $x = -3t+2, y = -5t+4, z = -6t-3$

Putting this in the equation of the plane,

$-3t+2 + 2(-5t+4) + 2(6t+3) - 9 = 0$

or, $t = 7$

So the point of intersection is $(-19, -31, -45)$

[Please check the calculations]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $(p,q,r)$ be any arbitrary point on the plane.
Let plane be $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ (You can easily solve the plane, I hope?

Now, A closest point to the $(0,3,-1)$ will be actually nothing but lying on perpendicular to the plane. Thus simply draw a line with points $(0,3,-1)$ and $(p,q,r)$ and intersect it with the plane to get the point.

NOTE: A line's equation . Let $(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(0,3,-1) $ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(p,q,r)$

Then Line:  $$\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}=\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$$

Also, intresting thing will be that this line will be parallel to plane's normal, Thus you may like to use that normal's DR for this equation $<A,B,C>$ to make the line:  $$\frac{x-x_1}{A}=\frac{y-y_1}{B}=\frac{z-z_1}{C}$$

Hope it solves both your questions.